# Get email body parsed upon Contact Form 7 submit

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to be able to use any of the contact form 7 hooks and get the email body with all the shortcodes already parsed.

I know you can get the email body with something like this:

```
function example_func(){
  $contactform = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
  // This would keep the email body with all the shortcodes 
  $mail_body = $contactform->prop('mail')['body'];
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','example_func');
```

However, what I'm looking for is a way to get EXACTLY what I get on my email. That email body with all the shortcodes replaced by the form values.

Comment: I think you would have to use the same functions that are used in the class `WPCF7_Mail` the actual shortcode replacement takes place in there, and is a private function `replace_tags_callback` - either that, or make something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The wpcf7_mail_replace_tags() function should do the trick.

```
function example_func(){
    $contactform = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $mail_body = $contactform->prop('mail')['body'];
    $mail_body = wpcf7_mail_replace_tags( $mail_body );
 }
 add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','example_func');
```